# ORA-06502 - buffer de string de caracteres pequeno demais numérico ou de valor - Campo Long

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle12c

Bom dia,
Estou realizando uma query para consultar dados em um campo do tipo Long.
Criei a seguinte Função para trazer os dados:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SEARCH_LONG" (r rowid) return varchar2 is
temporary_varchar varchar2(32000);
begin
select pm.ds_evolucao into temporary_varchar from dbamv.pre_med PM where rowid=r;
return temporary_varchar;
end;
```

Porem ao executar a consulta

```
SELECT pre.cd_atendimento,pre.hr_pre_med,pre.cd_prestador 
   from (select a1.cd_atendimento,search_long(a1.rowid) 
                ds_evolucao,a1.HR_PRE_MED,a1.CD_PRESTADOR
           from pre_med a1) pre
  where upper(pre.ds_evolucao) like '%SEPSE%'
       and pre.hr_pre_med > '01/08/2019'
       and cd_atendimento not in 
       (SELECT P.CD_ATENDIMENTO
          FROM ITPRE_MED IT 
          JOIN PRE_MED P ON IT.CD_PRE_MED = P.CD_PRE_MED
         WHERE CD_TIP_PRESC = 74076 )
```

Esta me retornando essa mensagem de erro:

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: erro: buffer de string de caracteres pequeno demais numérico ou de valor
> ORA-06512: em "DBAMV.SEARCH_LONG", line 5
> ```

Comment: Qual o tipo do seu dado da coluna `ds_evolucao`

Comment: Tipo Long @Sorack

Answer (score 2):

Substitua a linha

```
select pm.ds_evolucao into temporary_varchar
```

na função para:

```
select substr( pm.ds_evolucao, 1, 32000 ) into temporary_varchar
```

você vai ver que funciona. Acontece que o tamanho da string `pm.ds_evolucao` é maior do que comporta a variável `temporary_varchar`

**EDIÇÃO**

Teste transformando `LONG` em `VARCHAR2`

```
DECLARE
  VAR1 LONG;
  VAR2 VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  SELECT TEXT INTO VAR1 FROM USER_VIEWS WHERE ROWNUM = 1;  
  VAR2 := SUBSTR(VAR1, 1, 32000);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR2);
END;
```

Funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Retornou ORA-06575: Pacote ou função SEARCH_LONG está em um estado inválido

Comment: alter function `SEARCH_LONG` compile

Comment: Sim, eu fiz o Create or replace na função alterando a linha que me disse, porem continua dando esse erro que a função esta em um estado invalido.

Comment: drop a função e crie de novo ou recompile para tira-lá desse estado.

Comment: Exatamente, fiz o drop da função e a criei novamente.                        
DROP FUNCTION "SEARCH_LONG";

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SEARCH_LONG" (r rowid) return varchar2 is
temporary_varchar varchar2(32000);
begin
select substr(PM.ds_evolucao,1,31999) into temporary_varchar from dbamv.pre_med PM where rowid=r;
return temporary_varchar;
end;

Comment: Acredito que seja algum problema em usar o substr em campo do tipo Long que esta deixando ela invalida.

Comment: Não é isso Alterei a resposta e adicionei um teste que faz exatamente isso. Funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Pois é, estou usando exatamente como você me informou e como colei acima. Estou usando o Oracle 12c e o PL/SQL 12

Comment: ORA-01422: a extração exata retorna mais do que o número solicitado de linhas
ORA-06512: em line 4

Answer (score 1):

A sua coluna `ds_evolucao` é do tipo `LONG` e, quando você tenta converter para `VARCHAR2` sem explicitar o tamanho, o banco de dados tenta converte primeiramente para `CLOB` que tem um tamanho superior ao informado.

Para atribuir com sucesso você pode limitar o tamanho total do resultado com a função `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(pm.ds_evolucao, 1, 32000)
  INTO temporary_varchar
  FROM dbamv.pre_med PM
 WHERE rowid = r;
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso conforme o Sr Reginaldo me esclareceu em sua resposta, porem quando rodo a consulta apos compilar a function, ele me retorna que a função esta em um estado invalido.

Comment: @AlexandreQuirinodeFaria já tentou rodar só o conteúdo da função em uma janela separada para ver se a query é válida?

Comment: Sim, ja rodei ela quando não estava utilizando o substring, e se o período for menor ela retorna o resultado, porem se coloco um período maior para trazer mais registros, ela esta caindo nesse erro 06502.

Comment: @AlexandreQuirinodeFaria que período? Não tem período nenhum citado na sua pergunta. Sem todas as informações necessárias é impossível dar uma resposta pontual para o seu problema.

Comment: eu tenho duas querys, uma para criar a função e depois um select para trazer os dados em um periodo informado. conforme informado no primeiro post